# Related data object in null EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Hello recently I updated my project from core 2.1 to 2.2, after that when a object with a child is send from the form (Edit) comes the object with null Value (see imagen below), and the ModelState.IsValid is always false because is validating the null in the child class, please HELP!

https://i.ibb.co/hsmpc43/Screen-Shot-2019-04-16-at-11-03-17-AM.png

here is my class:

```
public class New : BaseEntity
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TowerID"), Display(Name = "Edificio")]
    public virtual Tower Tower { get; set; }
    public int TowerID { get; set; }

}
```

my controller:

```
[BreadCrumb(Title = "Editar", Order = 1)]
public IActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var news = _newBL.GetById(id);
    PopulateDropDowns();
    return View(news);
}
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(New value)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        value.Resources = _files;
        await _newBL.Update(value);
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    PopulateDropDowns();
    return View(value);
}
```

and my summit form:

```
<form asp-action="Edit" onsubmit="return disableButton(this);">

            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label asp-for="TowerID"></label>
                    <div class="custom-select">
                        <select asp-for="TowerID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.TowerID">
                            <option>Seleccione</option>
                        </select>

                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="TowerID" class="text-red"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    <label asp-for="CreatedDate">Creado en</label>
                    <label asp-for="CreatedDate" class="input-readonly" readonly>@Model.CreatedDate</label>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="CreatedDate" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    <label asp-for="Title"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" placeholder="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.Placeholder" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-red"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    <label asp-for="Message"></label>
                    <textarea id="summernote" asp-for="Message" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Message" class="text-red"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <button type="submit" class="btn green m-1" id="save"><i class="fas fa-save"></i> Guardar</button>
                <button asp-action="Index" type="submit" class="btn blue-darken-1 m-1"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Atras</button>
                <a  class="btn red m-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dangerModal">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Eliminar
                </a>
            </div>
        </form>
```

This only start happening when I updated to core 2.2 and is when I send the edit form with new values.

thanx in advance

UPDATE:

I tried changed back to core 2.1 and works, but when I switch back to 2.2 start happening, the tower object comes from the razor POST with all null values , but the news types don't (see image)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you're only posting the id for `Tower`, and that is indeed being populated. Nothing else for `Tower` is posted, so of course all the other properties are null or default. I'm not sure why you think this only just starting happening in 2.2, as this would have always been the case. In fact, it would be the case regardless of even what framework you were using. This could be Django or Ruby on Rails, and the `Tower` props would still all be null, because you aren't posting any of them.

HTTP is a stateless protocol. Nothing exists but what comes through the request itself. There is no memory of what these properties *used* to be because there's no knowledge there were was even a previous request made. You may interject something like sessions here, but that's essentially fake state. The server stores data associated with a session id and then transfers that session id to the client via a cookie. The client then must pass back that cookie containing the session id on each subsequent request to restore the session. Even then, the data is essentially still part of the request, it's just coming as a identifier to particular set of saved server-side data instead of the whole dataset.

Anyways, this is easily solved with a few tweaks to your code you should make regardless. First, you should never bind to an entity class directly. There's a number of reasons for this, but a chief concern is over-posting. With the code you have now, the client could alter the data sent to change something like the id of your entity, and you'd end up modifying the entity with *that* id, rather than the one that was actually being edited. Another rule related to this is that you should never directly save anything posted by the user, for many of the same reasons.

Instead, you should bind to a view model, and that view model should contain only the properties you actually want to allow the user to edit. Then, you fetch the entity fresh from the database and map over the posted values from the view model onto it, before finally saving the entity.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(NewViewModel value)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        PopulateDropDowns();
        return View(value);            
    }

    var entity = await _newBL.GetById(id);
    if (entity == null)
        return NotFound();

    entity.Title = value.Title;
    entity.Message = value.Message;
    entity.TowerID = value.TowerID;
    entity.Resources = _files;

    await _newBL.Update(entity);
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

The mapping part can be taken care of with a library like AutoMapper, if you prefer.

Comment: I Understand and thx for your time, In the Image there is an other child, "NewType" and in that case the object comes in null from the form, if is the same case , why only the tower comes with data? both of them are in the include when I search in "getbyid".

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this Issue you need to Include related datas ( Children ) in GetById() by adding somthing like this `.Include(blog => blog.Posts)` in your function 
**Documentation :** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data 
 or you need to activate lazyloading ( by default lazyloading is disabled ) 
 
**see more :** https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/lazy-loading

**Update :** 
In the case that the model comes null you need to aad a hidden input for all your model items to save their values when you submit your form. 
**example :**
 `<input type="hidden" asp-for="Tower.Id" />`

Comment: I Understand and thx for your time, In the Image there is an other child, "NewType" and in that case the object comes in null from the form, if is the same case , why only the tower comes with data? both of them are in the include when I search in "getbyid".

Comment: Please read the update of my answer , i hope that this solution can resolve your problem

Comment: Hello, doesn't the towerID is ok (see image) the tower is the only object comes from the HTML POST with all values in null, I try change back to core 2.1 and works, but when I switch back to 2.2 start happening